# How to flash a Hololens 1

Tags: factory-defaults, hololens

At work, I've inherited an old Hololens 1. Unfortunately, the configured credentials are long lost, so there seems to be no way of logging in to the device. I think that resetting it to factory state is the only thing left to do. I'm fine with that.

However, the first step in the [instructions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Hololens/blob/public/hololens/hololens1-recovery.md) is *Open the settings app*, which I cannot do without logging in.

I found a link to the [Device recovery tool](https://repairavoidance.blob.core.windows.net/packages/WindowsDeviceRecoveryToolInstaller.exe), which apparently can be used, but it seems to be dead.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Since this is linked to by the [official Microsoft instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq-2b186f06-7178-ed11-4cb6-5ed437f0855b), you must contact Microsoft and have them fix it.